# Where can I found the placeholder schema for camel?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint, property-placeholder

I want to use the following syntax to define a property attribute in a camel context like this:

```
<aggregate prop:completionSize="my.property" completionTimeout="1500" strategyRef=MyAggregationStrategy">
                ....
</aggregate>
```

and I cannot find anymore the schema `xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd

Comment: I already use this schema but I need to use a placeholder that refers to an integer value to avoid this exception  `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'my.property' is not a valid value for 'integer'.` I followed this guide http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: You have to tell that it's a property: {{my.property}}

Comment: I resolved changing the namespace using `xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"`